# Can`t get password from email using JavaMail

Tags: java, selenium, jakarta-mail

The site has the ability to reset the password. I want to write code of which the new password from the letter will be saved to the variable, which will be used in the test of profile editing. I'm using JavaMail.

Authorization to the mailbox goes through, finds an unread email with a specific subject, using getContent () displays the body of the message as text / html, but I can not figure out how to enter the message and get password from there.

```
    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.search.SubjectTerm;
    import java.util.Properties;

    public class Mail {
    //public static String pass = null;

    public Message getEmail(String emailID, String password, String subjectToBeSearched) throws Exception {

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", emailID, password);

        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        Message[] messages = null;
        boolean mailFound = false;
        Message email = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            messages = folder.search(new SubjectTerm(subjectToBeSearched), folder.getMessages());
            if (messages.length == 0) {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
        }

        for (Message mail : messages) {
            if (!mail.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {
                email = mail;
                mailFound = true;
                System.out.println("Mail is found");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(email.getContent());
        if (!mailFound) {
            throw new Exception("Could not found Email");
        }
        return email;
    }
}
```

**I call in the unit-test**

```
    import org.junit.Test;

    public class MailTest {
    @Test
    public void getEmail() throws Exception {
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.getEmail("test@gmail.com","11111","Password reset");
    }
}
```

**What I get using GetContent()**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>PSD2HTML</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .ExternalClass{display:block !important;}
        * {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
            -webkit-text-resize:100%;
            text-resize:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;" bgcolor="#ededeb" link="#0086da">
<style type="text/css">
    * {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
        -webkit-text-resize:100%;
        text-resize:100%;
    }
</style>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ededeb">
    <!--[if IE]>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table width="609" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if mso]>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table width="609" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
    <![endif]-->
    <tr>
        <td align="center" style="padding-top:47px; padding-bottom:46px; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;">
            <div style="max-width:599px; margin:0 auto;">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-bottom:1px solid #cdd1d2; margin:0 auto;">
                    <tr><td colspan="3" height="27" style="line-height:0; font-size:0;"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="8%"></td>
                        <td width="84%">
                                                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                                                                    <tr>
                                            <td style="font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:17px; color:#4c515a;">Hello, </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr><td height="10" style="line-height:0; font-size:0;"></td></tr>
                                                                            <tr>
        <td style="font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:17px; color:#4c515a;"><div style="line-height:10px; width:100%;"><span style="line-height:17px;">We have reset your password. Your login information with the new password is below.</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td height="14" style="line-height:0; font-size:0;"></td></tr>
                                </table>
                                                    </td>
                        <td width="8%"></td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#f9f9f9">
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#f9f9f9">
                                <tr><td colspan="3" height="16" style="line-height:0; font-size:0;"></td></tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="8%"></td>
                                    <td width="84%">
                                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="78" style="font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:10px; color:#4c515a; text-align:right;"><span style="line-height:17px;"><strong style="color:#000;">Login:&nbsp;</strong></span></td>
        <td style="font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:10px; color:#4c515a;"><span style="line-height:17px;">vlada.aleksandrova@p2h.com</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="78" style="font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:10px; color:#4c515a; text-align:right;"><span style="line-height:17px;"><strong style="color:#000;">Password:&nbsp;</strong> </span></td>
        <td style="font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:10px; color:#4c515a;"><span style="line-height:17px;">vtKKLzwb</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**So I need to parse this somehow**

Comment: Maybe it's just getting late here, but I'm not sure if I get the problem. You say that you can read the body of the mail, that contains the password. If you can do that, you have the password, just look for some specific pattern. Which part am I missing?

Comment: Yes, but I do not holw to write pattern and how to act with it. I am new in using java and webdriver but I want to solve this problem with javamail

Comment: In the most simple form it's something like this: `int start=mailBody.indexOf("your new password is:") + 21); int end=mailBody.indexOf("click here to login")); String password = mailBody.subString(start, end);` Look for the start of the password, and the end of it, then grab what is in between. Of course the start/end strings depend on the actual email you have.